# How to measure the lifetime of a particle experimentally?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, half-life

I'm wondering in experiment, how can one measure the lifetime of a particle, because it is a very short time.

Also, I'm wondering how experimentalists measure the mass of the particle, which is also very small

Comment: Do you mean the lifetime of a single, isolated particle, or of a type of particle?  For example, one free neutron may last a few milliseconds while another identical free neutron may last for a half hour.  But the half life of free neutrons in general is about 10.2 minutes.

Comment: @S.McGrew I mean a single particle, but it seems that in experiment people usually consider a bunch of particles? I'm just wondering if for experiments one could consider very few particle to measure the lifetime

Comment: In that case: the time between a single particle's creation and its decay can be measured by inferring its velocity from the kinetics of its creation event (e.g., tracks in a cloud chamber), and measuring the length of its track from creation to decay. Track length divided by velocity along the track equals that particle's lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example of both mass and lifetime measurements is provided by the delta baryon, which is produced in:

$$ e(p, e')\Delta $$

which means an electron beam (energy $E \gg m_e$) impinges on a proton target (mass $M$). The scattered electron (energy $E'\gg m_e$) is detected.  The invariant mass (squared) of the undetected final hadronic state is constructed from the usual deep inelastic scattering variables:

$$ W^2 = Q^2\frac{1-x}x $$

The cross section looks like:

[image]

In the resonance region, the virtual photon with energy $\nu$ produces a delta baryon which immediately decays:

$$ \gamma^* +p \rightarrow \Delta^+ \rightarrow p + \pi^0 $$

That reaction follows a Breit-Wigner resonance curve (which is the same shape as a driven spring or LCR circuit):

$$ \sigma(\nu) \propto \frac{\Gamma^2/4}{(\nu-M_\Delta)^2+\Gamma^2/4}$$

where $M_{\Delta}$ is the mass, and the width $\Gamma$ is related to the lifetime:

$$ \tau = \Gamma/\hbar \approx 5 \times 10^{-24}\,{\rm s}$$

The lifetime is as short as possible: it's time it takes light to traverse a proton, which is the fastest a 3 quark state can fall apart. Obviously, that cannot be measured with clocks, nor can the delta be tracked. Everything is inferred from the kinematics of other particles.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly hard to answer your question due to how general it is. There's a lot of ways these measurements can be done, and which ones are used in practice highly depends which ones are the most practical for the situation.

For a relatively simple to perform/understand method as an introduction, I recommend you look into bubble chamber analysis, which only needs basic classical mechanics to perform simpler measurements of this kind.

Comment: thank you very much! For example, in weak interaction, do people still use bubble chamber or there are more practical ways?

Comment: I just google the bubble chamber you mentioned. However, it seems that only works for charged particle, I'm wondering how to measure the lifetime of a neutral particle, like scalar or photon?

Comment: Bubble chambers are for most purposes considered obsolete (or at least very obsolescent) for cutting-edge physics on what it directly measures - however, it is something that is relatively simple to experimentally perform, understand, and use. I think it serves as a good introduction, and still has practical applications due to this simplicity.

Comment: For bubble chamber analysis, it can still indirectly measure neutral particles by looking at production and later collisions/decays.